# JavaScript function is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

Consider:

File **script.js**,

```
    function AdaugaComboBox(id, name){
        var select_tag = document.getElementById(id);
        select_tag.innerHTML += "<select name='"+name+"'><option value='0'>Selecteaza autor</option></select><br/>";
        return true;
    }
```

and file **index.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="autori">...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button"
                       value="Adauga autor"
                       onclick="AdaugaComboBox('autori', 'autori[]')"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The scope of the function is to add a combo box to the specific TD in the TABLE. But when I press the button this error appears:

> AdaugaComboBox is not defined

Why?

---

Update:

**!!! I've fixed it. The problem was with another function.**

Comment: script.js is not included anywhere in your HTML...

Comment: Where in the document tree is the function defined?

Comment: The script.js is included in the document and I get the same error.

Comment: The code that you have posted works fine for me in Chrome and IE - no errors.  If this is a shortened sample of your code, the error *must* be somewhere else.

Comment: I bet your script.js file isn't in a "js" sub directory, because it works fine.

Comment: I use Firefox and it need to work even here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the script is included in your HTML, then it's possible that you don't have the path correct based on the location of the HTML file.  Check with Firefox/Firebug to make sure that the JS file is being downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a reference to the script.js file.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: The script.js is included in the document and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="autori">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <input type="button" value="Adauga autor" onclick="AdaugaComboBox('autori', 'autori[]')"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script.js is included in the document and I get the same error.

Comment: Your script.js file must not be in a sub-directory called "js" then, because the code works fine.